# jQuery plugin Filthypillow - How do you manually save onblur?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, onblur

I have [this jquery plugin](http://aef-.github.io/jquery.filthypillow/) that I'm using for a timepicker. I have it working to show up when you click inside the text box. But I can't seem to "save" the time after clicking the save button. Is there a function for this plugin where I can save it after focusing out of the text box? What I've tried so far: `$(this).filthypillow("fp:save");`, `$(this).filthypillow("save");`, `$(this).filthypillow("updateDateTime");`, `$(this).filthypillow("saveDateTime");`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the link, it looks like you have to set the value on save:

```
$fp.on( "fp:save", function( e, dateObj ) {
    $fp.val( dateObj.format( "MMM DD YYYY hh:mm A" ) );
    $fp.filthypillow( "hide" );
} );
```

if you want to save on blur i'd suggest inspecting element on the save button, and finding the div/element that it is (the html that the plugin generates). then select it and register a click event like:

```
$('.fp-save-button').click();
```

in the blur handler to trigger the save action/event.

One way of making the datepicker close when you click off of it:

Add a div #mask with these styles :

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
display: none;
```

Then add `z-index: 2;` to the class fp-container.
Then in the javascript, show the #mask div when you focus the datepicker input, and bind a single click event (`one.('click', function(){}`) to it like this:

```
$fp.on( "focus", function( ) {
    $fp.filthypillow( "show" );
    $('#mask').show();
    $('#mask').one('click', function() {
        $('.fp-save-button').click();
        $('#mask').hide();
    });
} );
```

Comment: The first part fixed the save button. But how do I run the `fp:save` function on blur? This doesn't seem to work: `$fp.blur( function() {
   $(this).filthypillow( "fp:save" );
 } );`

Comment: That's what I was talking about--I don't think you can explicitly invoke the fp:save event. But what may work is invoking a click event on the save button, which will then cause the plugin to execute a save. Instead of `$(this).filthypillow` try `$('.fp-save-button').click();`

Comment: The menu goes away when I click on the text box again.

Comment: When you say on blur, do you want it to save and close with you mouseoff, or when you click off the datepicker?

Comment: Yes it should save and close when I click off the datepicker.

Comment: Blur may not be what you want, that has to do with an element losing focus, like when you click outside a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote filthypillow. You can do something like following:

```
$fp.on( "blur", function( ) {
    var date = $fp.filthypillow( "getDate" );
    if( $fp.filthypillow( "isValid" ) )
        saveDate( date );
} );

//This part isn't needed if you don't want to save with fp:save
$fp.on( "fp:save", function( e, dateObj ) {
    saveDate( dateObj );
} );
```

The idea is that you don't have to trigger fp:save to "officially" save.